# DateFormat parsing on MonoTouch

Tags: c#, android, .net, datetime, xamarin.ios

I have an sql query that saves a list of Dates (public holidays) to the database. This works fine on Windows and Android, but it fails on MonoTouch. It fails in the line below.

```
DateTime.Parse("01/01/2013").Date
```

It seems that MonoTouch is not able to parse this date. I know how to fix it by creating the DateTime object directly, but I just want to know if there is something that I am missing or is it a bug in MonoTouch?
I fixed it by instantiating the `DateTime` object directly like this:

```
new DateTime(2013,01,01)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you have your culture set to something that does not recognize "01/01/2013" as a default date format.  Your code works for me, but I am using "en-us" culture where MM/DD/YYYY is the standard format.

You can use Date.ParseExact() and specify a date format to override whatever the default for your culture is.

Comment: your profile says you're in Australia - I'm a little surprised this doesn't work for you.  What is your locale set to?

Comment: Thanks Json, you r right. It was actually failing in the next line (DateTime.Parse("26/01/2013")) [Australia Day], Once I change the locality on the Simulator it works fine. Thanks again